# free apache log analyzer with report of downloads of authenticated users

Tags: apache, logging

I'm looking a for free apache log analyzer tool which can be used to create a report like the one you can see by going [here](http://www.weblogexpert.com/sample/index.htm) and navigating to Visitors -> Requests of Users. In essence, I need to see for each authenticated user the actual files he/she has been downloading over a period of time, not their number or their kB count or some other statistic. I've found many tools that can do the latter ([awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/), [webalizer](http://www.mrunix.net/webalizer/), [w3perl](http://www.w3perl.com/) etc.), but none - free - that can do the former. If you know of any such tool, please help.

Answer (score 0):

The forthcoming w3perl 3.07 will be able to do what you want. You can try the dev package
and give me feedbacks in order to improve the reports.

Laurent